# How to set number of files that can be uploaded in flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I want to limit number of images per post request in flask so how can i do that

**My Code**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_uploads import UploadSet , IMAGES, configure_uploads

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/img/'
photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)

app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 4 * 1024 * 1024
app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
configure_uploads(app, photos)

@app.route('/upload/', methods=["POST","GET"])
def upload():
    if request.method == "POST" and 'photo' in request.files:
        photo = request.files['photo']
        photos.save(photo)
        return 'saved'
    else:
        return render_template("upload.html)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0", port="5000")
```

I want to be able to upload multiple files but limit only 2 at back-end

also is there a way to limit file upload in html?

**HTML Code**

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
  <div class="custom-file">
    <label for="customFile">Choose Cover Photo --Optional--</label>
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="customFile">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you share the Html code of file upload?

Comment: have updated the html code

Comment: HTML code that you have written will allow only one photo to be uploaded at a time. Need to understand what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to upload multiple files but limit only 2 at back-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code to handle the file limit from backend:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=["POST","GET"])
 def upload():
  if request.method == "POST" and 'photo' in request.files:
    uploaded_photos = request.files.getlist('photo')
    if len(uploaded_photos) > 2:
      error = "You are only allowed to upload a maximum of 2 files"
      return render_template("upload.html", error=error)
    else:
      for photo in uploaded_photos:
        photos.save(photo)
      return 'saved'
  else:
    return render_template("upload.html")
```

Need to specify multiple attribute in the input field of the file to allow multiple images to be uploaded at a time

```
{% if error %}
  <p class=error><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}</p>
{% endif %}
<form action="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
  <div class="custom-file">
    <label for="customFile">Choose Cover Photo --Optional--</label>
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="customFile" multiple>
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

You can handle it in frontend using jquery. Below is the code.

```js
$(function(){
   $("input[type = 'submit']").click(function(){
    var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
     if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 2){
       alert("You are only allowed to upload a maximum of 2 files");
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
  <div class="custom-file">
    <label for="customFile">Choose Cover Photo --Optional--</label>
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="customFile" multiple>
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
  </div>
</form>
```